# Is there a limit to how much stack space the VS2010 debugger can monitor for a given call?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm noticing some strange behavior while stepping through my code with the debugger, similar to the problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778570/visual-studio-debug-maximum-buffer-size).

For context, I have two VS2010 projects in my solution: a test executable, and a static library. Inside the library source file I have the following functions:

```
double LibClass::getFoo()
{
    double num;
    num = foo();
    return num;
}

double LibClass::foo()
{
    double A[65000];
    return 5.0;
}
```

This runs fine, and the debugger can step through these functions no problemo.

If, however, I increase the size of A as follows:

```
double LibClass::foo()
{
    double A[66000];
    return 5.0;
}
```

The debugger pops up a "No Source Available" tab when I step into foo(). I can still step through getFoo(), and foo() still returns 5.0, so there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code - just the debugger. Any idea what might be happening here? My only guess is that there must be some sort of limit to how much stack space the VS debugger can monitor for a given call. Is this the case? If so, how can I increase it?

Comment: Can you share a simple sample here? Do you mean that you want to increase the stack size? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744650/how-to-overcome-stack-size-issue-with-visual-studio-running-c-codes-with-big-ar or https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a5b32b6-683b-4729-92d3-45ed7a89ef3f/stack-overflow-and-how-to-increase-the-stack-size?forum=Vsexpressvc

Comment: @JackZhai - I'm not trying to increase the stack size, but rather the amount of stack space the VS2010 debugger is capable of monitoring. The local array in my code sample above is not enough to cause a stack overflow, but is enough to crash the debugger.